# How to build in C# one docx file from multiple docx templates and populate with data from SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ms-word, docx

I am new to .Net and I have been required to utilise a modular approach to generate invoices: to build one docx invoice out of several docx files, e.g. I have `header.docx`, `BalanceDue.docx` and so on and I need to create `invoice_number.docx` and populate with data from within SQL Server.

At the moment I have implemented it using `Interop.Word`: I have one Word `Application.Documents.Add` with `header.docx` file and then
from each of the other docx I extract table object, populate it cells and paste to the main header.docx one (I skip most of the steps, just showing the idea): 
.Active > .Tables > .Tables.Item > .Table.Cell and so on.

Two main issues I have:

1. Performance - as I have 12 docx files, the whole process of generating one invoice takes up to 5 seconds (!) and I have at least 500 invoices to generate in such a process.
2. Copy / Paste issue - I use Table.Range > Range.Copy > ActiveWindow.Selection.PasteAndFormat approach. what I have found that
   if, whilst the process is running for the above 500 invoices, I do PrintScreen or Ctrl+C, that content will be pasted (!) onto the invoice.

Any better approach one can advise, please? I have seen suggestions to use some 3rd party tools, but I am not allowed to during security restrictions.

Comment: I'd *strongly* recommend ditching Word Interop (slow and requires Word on the machine) and using the `OpenXML` libraries directly - [see this CodeProject article on how to do this](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/666751/Use-OpenXML-to-Create-a-Word-Document-from-an-Exis) - or alternatively [this other CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/660478/Csharp-Create-and-Manipulate-Word-Documents-Progra)

Comment: The OpenXML tool that comes packaged with the SDK (http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=30425) is *extremely* useful for getting started. You can load any OpenXML (Word/Excel/whatever) document into it and have the C# code to generate that document displayed alongside. The generated code is a wee bit of a horror to read through as there's a gigantic heap of 'unnecessary' cruft in there, but with some judicious searching you can pick out the important parts.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. Can you point me to any example with multiple docx files loading into one docx using OpenXML, please?
I would assume it is better to load first into one docx and then populate all the fields, no?